# Change print format of a Date without converting it to character

Tags: r, date

With a `Date` object in R, is it possible to choose a different print format than the default `"%Y-%m-%d"` while keeping its `Date` class? The `format()` function converts it back to a `character` string.

```
# I start with a character string and convert it to a date
date_char <- "01-05-2015"
date <- as.Date(date_char, format = "%d-%m-%Y")

# By default, R re-formats the date as "%Y-%m-%d"
date
# [1] "2015-05-01"

# I want to keep the Date class, but with the original format
# format() converts it back to a character variable
str(format(date, "%d-%m-%Y"))
# chr "01-05-2015"
```

Comment: You would need to write a new `print.Date` method, but why do you care about the *printed* representation of the object?

Comment: Aesthetics, mostly. It would be nice to write code with dates in the same format that will appear in graphics later.

Comment: Why are you writing code that depends on how an object _prints_?

Comment: My honest answer is cognitive load. It takes one extra mental step to think of dates in two separate formats, though it hardly matters in the end.

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't be writing code that depends on how objects print. You're asking for extra cognitive load when something goes wrong with the parsing to/from character/Date.

Comment: It's probably best to leave this as an interesting philosophical debate. Computer programmers produce code as their product; as a scientist, I produce information and graphics as my product. Because I'm the only person who reads my code, efficiency in the *process* of coding is more important to me than efficiency in the code itself. Cognitive load is the finite resource that I aim to maximize, and that's why I asked this question.

Comment: I'm not referring to the efficiency of the code. Your "efficient process of coding" may result in bugs and/or make it hard for others to reproduce your analysis. For example, `POSIXct` objects are not printed with a time component if the time is midnight ("00:00"). If you rely on the time always being printed, you could have a problem. And it would likely take you quite awhile to track it down.

Comment: You're right to think that I care about avoiding bugs. Unless you can think of a reason G. Grothendieck's answer is error-prone, this is going to be my last comment here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a subclass of Date with its own print method but its probably not worth it.

If you use chron then you can associate a format with each object:

```
library(chron)

c1 <- chron(c("02/27/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92")); c1
## [1] 02/27/92 02/27/92 01/14/92

c2 <- chron(c("02/27/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92"), out.format = "y-mmm-d"); c2
## [1] 1992-Feb-27 1992-Feb-27 1992-Jan-14
```

Comment: Thanks; this is much more efficient than writing a new ```print.Date``` method