# Preserve %d-%b-%Y as Date rather than character in R tibble

Tags: r, date, format, tibble, as.date

Suppose I look at the date March 5th:

```
> temp <- as.Date("05-Mar-2021", "%d-%b-%Y")
> temp
[1] "2021-03-05"
> tibble(temp)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  temp      
  <date>    
1 2021-03-05
```

Note that the tibble correctly says it's a date. Now I want a different format.

```
> temp <- format(as.Date("05-Mar-2021", "%d-%b-%Y"), "%d-%b-%Y")
> temp
[1] "05-Mar-2021"
> tibble(temp)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  temp       
  <chr>      
1 05-Mar-2021
```

Notice this is a character. Is there a way I can get the tibble to still be of class `Date` (`<date>` in the tibble) but to print in the format `05-Mar-2021`?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a `character` class as the format required by `Date` class is `'%Y-%m-%d`.  May be you can define a new typedef/datatype with that format

Comment: +1 Henrik, I've always suggested that R displays it the way R displays it, not thinking about overriding the class with a personal function. This method also works with `POSIXct`. (Granted, it'll likely be somewhat fragile if pipelines don't carry-forward the class, but that's a different story.)

Comment: Also note the objections in comments here: [Change print format of a Date without converting it to character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790647/change-print-format-of-a-date-without-converting-it-to-character), and a `chron` alternative.

Comment: @Henrik Naive question, but how would I get the tibble to actually print the news date format? Wouldn’t I have to make a substantial change to the tibble class? Apologies if I’m missing something.

Comment: A trip down the rabbit hole. Seems like [package `pillar`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pillar/pillar.pdf) formats tibbles. See `pillar_shaft`, ## S3 method for class `Date`. Then [here](https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/blob/master/R/shaft-.R#L173-L174)...tadaa!...`date <- format(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")`. So if you try e.g. [`prettyDate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36126372): `m = prettyDate(m)`; `class(m)`; `tibble(m)`. Indeed recognized as a `Date` (`<date>`), but using the `format` from `pillar_shaft`. I agree with the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27790647)...;)

Comment: @Henrik: Yup, was able to replicate -- so you're suggesting overwriting pillar_shaft?

Comment: I found this question in the reopen queue. I don't think it's a very good duplicate of the suggested targets, so I voted to reopen it. You may find some help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65460421/13095326).